# Minting ERC20 on ETH and Polygon

Tags: ether, polygon

I am looking for creating an ERC20 smart contract on ETH and mapping it to Polygon.

The idea is to have 100.000 tokens available in total and allow users to mint from both sides.

Is this possible? I was not able to find any good articles about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global capped layerZero OFT template to launch a token contract across several chains https://github.com/LayerZero-Labs/solidity-examples/blob/main/contracts/token/oft/extension/GlobalCappedOFT.sol